# Implementing wavesurfer-js in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, wavesurfer.js

I am implementing wavesurfer-js in typescript project, the player opens but i can't find any controls to play pause or mute events,

Index.HTML

```
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
   <div id="waveform"></div>
```

TS

```
    import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
    var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio-page',
  templateUrl: './audio-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio-page.component.scss'],
})

    export class AudioPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private bottomSheetRef: 
MatBottomSheetRef<AudioPageComponent>) { }

  audiofile = 
 "http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/
song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3";

  ngOnInit() {

  wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: '#waveform',
  waveColor: '#a8d4e4',
  progressColor: '#1a99be',
  backend: 'MediaElement',
});

  wavesurfer.load(this.audiofile);

  wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
  wavesurfer.play();

  });


}


  openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

When I try to bind an event like

```
(click)="wavesurfer.playPause()"
```

It gives an error "Cannot read property 'playPause' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the WaveSurfer object like this:

```
this.waveSurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: '#waveform',
  ..
});

this.waveSurfer.waveSurfer.play();
```